# How do append to a list using user input that stays in the list?

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, input

I'm working on an email list program for my band, and although I found out how to append to the list of fans using **user input**, when I restart the program the information doesn't stay in there. I want to be able to turn the program into an executable application where you can input information and it permanently saves. Just so I'm not giving out emails and names and locations, I created an example and then after the example I will put an **Imgur** link to what the console looks like if I search **All Data** while the **loop** is still running and what it looks like once I restart the program and try again(it doesn't show up when I restart):

```
class Emails:
    def __init__(self, name, location, email):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.email = email


fans = [Emails('james franco', 'california', 'jamesfranco@gmail.com'),
        Emails('john cena', 'california', 'johncena@hotmail.com')
        ]


def append_input():
    input_name = input('Add Name: ')
    input_location = input('Add Location: ')
    input_email = input('Add Email: ')
    fans.append(Emails(input_name, input_location, input_email))


def all_data():
    for fan in fans:
        print(fan.name + '\n')
        print(fan.location + '\n')
        print(fan.email + '\n________________')



while True: 
    start_search = input("What would you like to search?(Name/Location/Email/All Data/Add Data): ")
    if start_search == "Add Data":
        append_input()
    if start_search == "All Data":
        all_data()
```

[Before refreshing console and inputing "all data" to check(works fine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWPHO.png)

[After refreshing console and inputing "all data" to check. Lil wayne is not there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5no1.png)

You guys have saved me many times, but if you save me with this, then my entire program is basically finished. Thank you for your kindness and the time you take to answer all of my questions friends!

Answer (score 0):

In order for data to be saved and persist across multiple runs, you have to actually save it to file on disk or database. If you don't do it, it only stays in memory for the duration of the program and getting wiped when program exits.

Persistent storage can be a simple CSV file that you load when program starts up and save entries there as users input. However, DB (such as SQLite) might be better as you can index data, avoid duplicate entries, query it, etc.

Python has modules for both CSV and SQLite and other DBs. Here is SQLite tutorial:
https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_sqlite_in_python_tutorial.html